# Layout Challenge in HTML / CSS page

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, snap.js

I'm working on a web app. This app is using Bootstrap, AngularJS, and Snap.js. I'm just trying to setup the basic layout and drawer of my app. However, I can't seem to get the drawer to behave properly. I'm trying to create a site that looks like the following:

```
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
+ Hello                                               | 
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| Nav Item 1    | Main content here                   |
| Nav Item 2    | [toggle]                            |
| Nav Item 3    |                                     |
|               |                                     |
|               |                                     |
|               |                                     |
|               |                                     |
|               |                                     |
|               |                                     |
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
```

When a user clicks the [toggle] button, I want to toggle (collapse or expand) the area with the nav items. That area should not cover the main content. Instead, it should push it to the right when it expands. The banner should not move. In an attempt to do this, I'm using snap.js and angular snap. Currently, I have the following HTML, which can be used in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tk53D/):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <header class="header fixed-top clearfix" style="left:0px; right:0px; z-index:5000;" role="navigation">
        <div style="float: left; background-color:black; color:white;">
            <a href="/">Hello</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <aside>
            <snap-drawer style="background-color:red; width:240px;">
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                I'm the navigation!
            </snap-drawer>
        </aside>

        <snap-content id="page-content" snap-id="pageContent">
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

            Main content here
            <button snap-toggle="">Toggle</button>
        </snap-content>
    </main>
</div>
```

For some reason, my main content always sits on top of my nav content. In addition, the nav items and main content are not actually below the banner. Its like the banner sits on top of the content. From what I can tell, I have two issues that I believe are related. However, I can't figure out the core issue. Those two issues are:

1. The nav and content are not positioned under the banner. Its like the banner floats on top of the nav and content.
2. The nav area does not expand and collapse. Its like the nav items stay fixed in position and only the main content moves.

Thank you for any help. Once again the fiddle can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tk53D/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need, hope this works for you.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6yx8h/1/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. However, I really need to use snap.js as it provides some other features that I need to make use of. I sincerely appreciate your attempt though.

Comment: @Pinki Make sure you edit your answer to include code so that it doesn't end up getting deleted.